# Return value to error callback function using PHP and angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need to return value to error call back function when the sql query will not execute using PHP and angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Oditek123@", "******");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM db_Admin_Master WHERE id=". $_SESSION["admin_id"]);
$data = array();
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    print json_encode($data);
?>
```

> dashboardController.js:

```
var dashboard=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('dashboardController',function($scope,$http){
     $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'php/Login/session.php',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
     }).then(function successCallback(response){
         //console.log('session',response);
         $scope.userType=response.data[0].user_name;
     },function errorCallback(response) {
         //console.log('session',response);
     });
})
```

Here my requirement is when the query will execute the variable `$data` will return to success callback function and when it will not execute due to any wrong id some message will return to error call back function.Please help me.

Comment: The `response` callback param only expects for a server status code, not an SQL error. So by all means, if you get query error, you're going to receive success if the promise of the HTTP request is fulfilled, but the response will be SQL error. You have to check for error inside PHP and handle it there. [For reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: @AlanMachado : i dont get any sql related error ,i just need to return value as per my requirement.Here all time the value is returning to success call back function.

Comment: I think you need to change your PHP script to send some error status code like 4XX or 5XX in response in case of any query error. Only then, error callback will be invoked and you can deal with that

Comment: Which is exactly what happens. Note that your PHP don't test your query for errors, it assumes it'll ever succeed. You could 'forge' your query test to send some HTTP status response, so errorCallback would be called, but I'd not recommend it since you'll be escaping the purpose of the error callback, that is handling HTTP status directly related problems.

Comment: @Arkantos : Here i dont have any error.My requirement is when the select query will not execute due to any wrong id then the alsert message will return to error call back function.

Comment: *Your requirement can not be met without a workaround, because errorCallback is not fit for the purpose you want*

Comment: @AlanMachado : Think suppose no session is present ,i need to return one message to error call back function.

Comment: @AlanMachado : Can you share your own idea for this requirement.

Comment: Ok, so in the session situation you could send like 401 code, then errorCallback would be called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91735/discussion-between-satya-and-alan-machado).

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` `response` callback parameter expects a *server status code*, not an SQL error or any other kind of message. So by all means, if you get a query error (or even a successful query with no results), you're going to receive **success** if the promise of the HTTP request is fulfilled, but the response will be the SQL error message (or code), if ever handled.

You have to check for query issues inside PHP and handle it there. Then, if you want, you can send headers with a new HTTP status response, or just raw message text.

Ex:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Oditek123@", "******");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM db_Admin_Master WHERE id=". $_SESSION["admin_id"]);
$data = array();
if ($result) { // if everything goes ok
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
} else { // else, send error
    $data['errno'] = mysqli_errno($connect);
    $data['error'] = mysqli_error($connect);
}
        print json_encode($data);
?>
```